# Почему мне нельзя поменять две строки местами через третью?

Tags: kotlin, swap

Пишу метод на , который принимает две строки и меняет их значения через третью строку. Но появляется ошибка. Idea пишет, что переменная val не может быть переинициализирована. Но у меня нет val переменных в коде. Не подскажете, что не так? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Аргументы метода str1 и str2 являются immutable, т.е. неизменяемыми, а вы пытаетесь им присвоить другую ссылку

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Они являются immutable, потому что это строки? Просто с числами та же ситуация получается.

Comment: @ЮрийХмелевских, не знаю что у вас получается, но с числами такое тоже не получится сделать: https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLjQxIiwiY29kZSI6ImZ1biBtYWluKCkge1xuICAgIHZhciBhID0gMVxuICAgIHZhciBiID0gMlxuICAgIHN3YXAoYSwgYilcbiAgICBwcmludGxuKGEpXG4gICAgcHJpbnRsbihiKVxufVxuXG5mdW4gc3dhcCh4OiBJbnQsIHk6IEludCkge1xuICAgIHZhciB0ZW1wID0geFxuICAgIHggPSB5XG4gICAgeSA9IHRlbXBcbn1cbiIsInBsYXRmb3JtIjoiamF2YSIsImFyZ3MiOiIifQ==

Comment: А какая разница? Числа или строки. У вас аргументы неизменяемы.

Comment: То есть в Kotlin аргументы, которые передаются в метод всегда неизменяемые?

Comment: Именно. Если вы хотите изменять их, то создайте внутри метода ещё одну переменную и присвойте ей значение аргумента

Comment: Спасибо большое)